# How to update outlook mail body text before sending

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I am working on an Outlook add-in to handle email attachments by placing them on a server and putting a URL in the email instead.

One problem is that after adding the URL to the end of the email body the user's cursor is reset to the start of the email.

A related problem is that I do not know where the cursor is in the text so I cannot insert my URL into the correct location.

Here is some code showing what I am doing, for simplicity the code is assuming the body is plain text.

---

```
 private void MyAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        Application.ItemLoad += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(Application_ItemLoad);
    }

   void Application_ItemLoad(object Item)
    {

        currentMailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

        ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)currentMailItem).BeforeAttachmentAdd += new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_BeforeAttachmentAddEventHandler(ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentAdd);


    }
void ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentAdd(Outlook.Attachment attachment, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        string url = "A URL";
        if (currentMailItem.BodyFormat == Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML)
        {
            // code removed for clarity
        }
        else if (currentMailItem.BodyFormat == Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatRichText)
        {
            // code removed for clarity
        }
        else
            currentMailItem.Body += attachment.DisplayName + "<" + url + ">";

       Cancel = true;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433898/c-sharp-outlook-how-can-i-get-the-cursor-position-in-the-subject-field-of-a-ma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Application.ActiveInspector.WordEditor` to retrieve the Word Document object. Perform all the changes using Word Object Model.

Comment: Thanks, I was just looking in that area.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do what I want:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    void ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentAdd(Outlook.Attachment attachment, ref bool Cancel)
    {
         if (attachment.Type == Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue)
        {
            string url = "A URL";
             Document doc = currentMailItem.GetInspector.WordEditor;
            Selection objSel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
            object missObj = Type.Missing;

            doc.Hyperlinks.Add(objSel.Range, url, missObj, missObj, attachment.DisplayName, missObj);

            Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```